# Finite difference between old and new OpenMDAO

Tags: openmdao

So I am converting a code from the old OpenMDAO to the new OpenMDAO. All the outputs and the partial gradients have been verified as correct. At first the problem would not optimize at all and then I realized that the old code had some components that did not provide gradients so they were automatically finite differenced. So I added fd_options['force_fd'] = True to those components but it still does not optimize to the right value. I checked the total derivative and it was still not correct. It also takes quite a bit longer to do each iteration than the old OpenMDAO. The only way I can get my new code to optimize to the same value as the old OpenMDAO code is to set each component to finite difference, even on the components that provide gradients. So I have a few questions about how finite difference works between the old and the new OpenMDAO:

1. When the old OpenMDAO did automatic finite difference did it only do it on the outputs and inputs needed for the optimization or did it calculate the entire Jacobian for all the inputs and outputs? Same question for the new OpenMDAO when you turn 'force_fd' to True.
2. Can you provide some parts of the Jacobian of a component and have it finite difference the rest? In the old OpenMDAO did it finite difference any gradients not provided unless you put missing_deriv_policy = 'assume_zero'?

Answer (score 2):

1. So, the old OpenMDAO looked for groups of components without derivatives, and bundled them together into a group that could be finite differenced together. New OpenMDAO doesn't do that, so each of those components would be finite differenced separately.
2. We don't support that yet, and didn't in old OpenMDAO. We do have a story up on our pivotal tracker though, so we will eventually have this feature.

What I suspect might be happening for you is that the finite-difference groupings happened to be better in classic OpenMDAO. Consider one component with one input and 10 outputs connected to a second component with 10 inputs and 1 output. If you finite difference them together, only one execution is required. if you finite difference them individually, you need one execution of component one, and 10 executions of component two. This could cause a noticeable or even major performance hit.

Individual FD vs group FD can also cause accuracy problems, if there is an important input that has vastly different scaling than the other variables, so that the default FD stepsize of 1.0e-6 is no good. (Note: you can set a `step_size` when you add a param or output and it overrides the default for that var.)

Luckilly, new OpenMDAO has a way to recreate what you had in old OpenMDAO, but it is not automatic. What you would need to do is take a look at your model and figure out what components can be FD'd together, and then create a sub Group and move those components into that group. You can set `fd_options['force_fd']` to True on the group, and it'll finite difference that group together. So for example, if you have A -> B -> C, with no components in between, and none have derivatives, you can move A, B, and C into a new sub Group with force_fd set to True.

If that doesn't fix things, we may have to look more deeply at your model.

Comment: So I think you're right but I'm having a hard time implementing it. The code has a lot of components that depend on lots of other components. It will be hard for me to find everywhere all the finite groups could be. Every time I've tried doing a finite difference group it keeps wanting me to change the solver so it can do a cycle. I'll do my best, but think it would be awesome to change the new OpenMDAO to do the automatic finite difference as well. Thanks!

Comment: if you model is so complex, that you can't easily identify chains of components that don't provide derivatives by hand, then perhaps you have a model complexity issue that needs to be solved first. But another option is just to implement derivatives for all your components!